# Invalid conversion when calling from command line (C++)

Tags: c++, command-line

I do not understand why the following is not working. I've read from several sources that this is the right way to pass the arguments to the function, and I've printed the contents of `argv` succesfully.

The idea is to call the program from the command line, where it will work with all the arguments passed above 5 (so application name + 5 others should be ignored). What is still going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

std::vector<int> createEndBlock(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> blocks; 
  for (int i = 6; i < (argc - 6); i++)
    {
      string str = argv[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++)
        { 
          if (str[j] == '-') {
            blocks.push_back(atoi(str.substr(j+1).c_str()));
            cout<<blocks[i]<<endl;
          }
        }
    }
  return blocks;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> blocks;
  blocks = createEndBlock(argc, argv);

  for (int i = 6; i < 7; i++)
    {
      cout<<blocks[i]<<endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:38:37: error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’ 
                       [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:19:18: error: initializing argument 2 of ‘std::vector<int>
                       createEndBlock(int, const char**)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Compiled:
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11

Example for the command line:

```
./test not not not not not 1-2 4-5 7-10
```

Should result in:

```
2 5 10
```

Comment: @BoBTFish This signature of `main` is _not_ standard conforming.

Comment: Ooh good point. Sorry! (Well it is conforming in that The Standard allows other possible definitions for `main`, but it is not one of the two guaranteed to be valid).

Comment: @BoBTFish Well yes, a compiler is _allowed_ to implement other signatures. Often enough `void main()` is accepted. But who would like to rely on a specific compiler for the entry point of a program?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indices are incorrect:

```
for (int i = 6; i < (argc - 6); i++)
```

That reads as "start from 6 to 6 from the end. Change (argc - 6) to just argc.

And in main, you want to read blocks from 0 to blocks.size() - 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `char * []` for main, and pass that to a function expecting `const char * []`. They don't match.

You should remove the `const` from `createEndBlock`

```
std::vector<int> createEndBlock(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: It compiles, but gives me a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. After your edit, still the same error.

Comment: Why the constness would be the source of the problem ?

Comment: Make sure you are not reading outside the bounds of the array. Try debugging or using output statements to determine where it is crashing.

Comment: @nouney the key error message is "invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’"

Comment: @crashmstr How to debug this? Also, how could this possibly be out of bounds? There is a limit on the arg count?

Comment: I don't know that values for argv that are *not* set are zeroed out, but you could be using uninitialized memory if you go outside of what argc is. You should always check that. Also, the `for (int i = 6; i < 7; i++)` in main seems pretty shaky. Are you sure you have 7 elements?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

- Remove const from the signature of *createEndBlock()*
- Add const to the signature of *main()*
- Use **const_cast<>** to add constness when calling *createEndBlock()*

Comment: Adding `const` to the signature of `main` is not standard conforming and therefore relies on the compiler. It should be avoided.

Comment: +1 stefan is farming stack overflow with that statement :-)

Comment: @Dualinity Well I wouldn't say "farming", but yeah, I do.

Answer (score 0):

Your `blocks[i]` statements could have invalid indices passed to them. Look again at your inner loop for createEndBlock. You check for a particular condition, only adding a new block if that condition is met. Well, what happens if the test fails when i=0 then passes when i=1 ? Simple, you then try to access blocks[**1**], yet it only has a single element, blocks[**0**].  Result? BOOM!

Comment: Wow yea... I carelessly copied the previous for loop. The problem is that it should start at `i=0`.

Comment: Or at least I thought. The error lies in the for loop in main.